# bash parameter substitution with newline

Tags: bash, arraylist, newline, substitution

My shell scripting seems to be a bit rusty. My desire is to loop over an arraylist configuration variable in bash and call a function with the necessary parameters obtained inside this loop, all without forking.

Basically, I have created what shall be called an inside-script human-parseable comma-separated configuration variable like follows:

```
CONFIG="
     0, 0x00, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' %
     1, 0x01, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' %
    51, 0x10, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' %
    63, 0xd4, 'Power up and unmute DAC' %
    64, 0x00, 'Power up and unmute DAC' %
"
```

I would then like to loop over its parameters like so:

```sh
while read reg val expl; do
    printf "%s %s\n" "Calling i2c_write() with reg=${reg//,/}" \
          "val=${val//,/} expl=$expl __EOL__";
    # i2c_write() call
done <<< "${CONFIG//\%/$'\n'}"
```

The current output is:

```
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=0 val=0x00 expl='Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=1 val=0x01 expl='Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=51 val=0x10 expl='Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=63 val=0xd4 expl='Power up and unmute DAC' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=64 val=0x00 expl='Power up and unmute DAC' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg= val= expl= __EOL__
```

The desired output would be:

```
Calling i2c_write() with reg=0 val=0x00 expl='Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=1 val=0x01 expl='Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=51 val=0x10 expl='Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=63 val=0xd4 expl='Power up and unmute DAC' __EOL__
Calling i2c_write() with reg=64 val=0x00 expl='Power up and unmute DAC' __EOL__
```

I'm happy to replace the CONFIG variable with a more suitable structure, as long as:

- a) No forks are needed to loop through the entries of the variable, and
- b) it's reasonably easy to humanly parse and edit the entries of said variable, and
- c) it works with bash 3.2.x upwards.

Comment: Having read all the working solutions, I always had the feeling that my attempt was rather convoluted; I just couldn't find a proper solution. I would like to thank Peter.O, Sorpigal, and ormaaj for their inspiring comments and the beautifully crafted self-explanatory code snippets. It's great to pick up something new every day.

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary to keep this convoluted CONFIG format?

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
CONFIG="
     0, 0x00, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
     1, 0x01, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
    51, 0x10, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
    63, 0xd4, 'Power up and unmute DAC'
    64, 0x00, 'Power up and unmute DAC'
"

while IFS=,$'\n ' read -r reg val expl; do
    [ -z "$reg" ] && continue
    printf "%s %s\n" "Calling i2c_write() with reg=${reg}" \
          "val=${val} expl=$expl __EOL__";
    # i2c_write() call
done <<< "${CONFIG}"
```

I simply replaced `%` with a literal newline, since you did that later anyway, and made `,` also a delimiter. I also threw in a test to skip the leading and trailing empty lines.

You could, if you must, keep the `%` to newline translation and the rest stays the same.

EDIT:

If you are even less bound by keeping your convoluted CONFIG format, may I propose the following alternative?

```
#!/bin/bash

config+=(0 0x00 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338')
config+=(1 0x01 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338')
config+=(51 0x10 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338')
config+=(63 0xd4 'Power up and unmute DAC')
config+=(64 0x00 'Power up and unmute DAC')

for((i=0;i<${#config[@]};i+=3)) ; do
    reg=${config[$i]}
    val=${config[$i+1]}
    expl="${config[$i+2]}"
    printf "Calling i2c_write() with reg=%d val=%s expl='%s' __EOL__\n" \
            $reg $val "$expl"
    # i2c_write() call
done
```

This presumes that you always have sets of 3 parameters, which appears true, and avoids messy parsing logic. It should be slightly more efficient. I've also changed the `printf` to be simpler.

EDIT 2:
Competing with Peter.O, here's a version which runs in `sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
CONFIG="
     0, 0x00, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
     1, 0x01, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
    51, 0x10, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
    63, 0xd4, 'Power up and unmute DAC'
    64, 0x00, 'Power up and unmute DAC'
"

echo "$CONFIG" | while IFS=' ', read -r reg val expl; do
    [ -z "$reg" ] && continue
    printf "Calling i2c_write() with reg=%d val=%s expl=%s __EOL__\n" \
            $reg $val "$expl"
    # i2c_write() call
done
```

Comment: Interesting solution: I certainly didn't know about the "IFS=,$'\n '" part. On second though, the convoluted CONFIG is at best a hindrance to the legibility of the code, since it'll eventually grow beyond an acceptable measure and will have to be put into a separate config file all together. I thoroughly enjoyed your second version, and if I am not mistaken, you'll enter a sub-shell in your third option.

Comment: @Moreaki: The sub shell in the third version is due to the pipe only. You could use a here sting as Peter.O did and avoid this; in fact, now that I think about it a here string in which `$CONFIG` is expanded would accomplish what I wanted (isolate the declaration of CONFIG away from the processing of its contents) without causing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will run is `sh` so I presume it will run in `bash 3.1`.  It didn't like the `reg` and `var` parameter substitutions (`//,/`) so I just changed them to truncate the  comma.  and changed the input method to `here-doc` vs your `here-string`

I'm not sure why you have `%` at the end of each input line. Was it just to put a newline there? (but there is already a newline there and `%` substitution just adds blank lines)...

Here is the modified script

```
while read -r reg val expl; do
    printf "%s %s %s\n" \
      "Calling i2c_write() with reg=${reg%,}" \
                               "val=${val%,}" \
                               "expl=$expl __EOL__";
done <<EOF
     0, 0x00, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
     1, 0x01, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
    51, 0x10, 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
    63, 0xd4, 'Power up and unmute DAC'
    64, 0x00, 'Power up and unmute DAC'
EOF
```

---

Here is an `awk` version (just for the sake of comparison). It reads the same data.

```
awk -vFS=\' '{split($1,f," ")
              split(f[1]f[2],f,",")
              print "Calling i2c_write() with" \
                     " reg=" f[1] \
                     " val=" f[2] \
                     " expl="FS $2 FS" __EOL__"
}' <<EOF
:: data ::
END
```

and `sed` for good measure ...

```
sed -nr "s/^ +([0-9]+), +([0-9a-fx]+), +('.*')$/\
Calling i2c_write() with reg=\1 val=\2 expl=\3 __EOL__/p
" <<EOF
:: data ::
END
```

Comment: I completely forgot about the here-document approach ;). Thank you as well for the awk and sed version. The '%' delimiter initially chosen out of despair was as ugly as a pig licking piss off a nettle. I have slightly modified the comment part from single quotes to double quotes, adhering to a more sane CSV specification.

Comment: @Moreaki: Be careful with double quotes. Single quotes are safer because they assure that the shell will not process the contents at all, whereas with double quotes you have no such assurance.

Answer (score 1):

```
main() {
    local a n
    while read -r a; do
        local -a 'args=('"$a"')'
        printf "%s reg=%s val=%s expl='%s' __EOL__\n" 'Calling i2c_write() with' "${args[@]}"
        # i2c_write {reg,val,expl}"=${args[n++%3]}"
    done <<"EOF"
0 0x00 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
1 0x01 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
51 0x10 'Reset the chip, enable PLL with P=4, R=1, J=9, D=6338'
63 0xd4 'Power up and unmute DAC'
64 0x00 'Power up and unmute DAC'
EOF
}

main
```

I assume you're trying to store "structs" of 3 fields here and pass them as 3 separate arguments. The commented line is how I'd expect you'll probably be calling the command. The question isn't very clear about what the arguments getting passed should be since your printf is getting passed just one. If that's the case then this problem is much simpler.

Assuming you're using a shell with arrays, you absolutely want an array. Unfortunately Bash lacks multi-dimensional arrays, and bash <4.0 lacks associative arrays, which essentially leaves a choice between indirection, and parsing commands in strings - both of which are ugly. Personally I would try using arrays anyway.

The above undocumented, non-portable, not guaranteed future-safe hack should otherwise be "safe" on Bash 3 through the present version and meets your requirements. The bash 3 restriction is very painful since we can't use `printf -v`, and no forks means no command substitution, which means no `printf '%q'`. Basically each line of the heredoc must be what would ordinarily be the valid contents of a compound assignment (properly quoted and escaped).

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: Your solution offered me some interesting insights into tackling future problems of reading and serving arrays throughout the context of a bash shell. Thank you very much.

On a side-node, I have been inspired by your comment with regard to the lack of associative arrays and come up with a half-backed solution to this issue:

Comment: I'm working on a library for generalizing passing/returning arrays and simple higher-order functions but its not quite on Github yet. This particular behavior is *[obscure](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2004-09/msg00135.html)*. I have a more complicated example here if needed: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#indirection . If you need better datastructures, can't use a non-shell language, and performance is important, I'd recommend looking at a current ksh93 version instead.

Comment: While waiting for bitback/openembedded to compile the world, I've quickly hacked up something using hashes: http://pastebin.com/THFkY7BE

It's really slow and has an unfortunate parameter expansion bug, however it could serve people's needs. I sometimes used zsh or ksh93, often though the problem to be solved must be implemented in orders of magnitude faster than the existing version. This almost always has resulted in a rewrite in either Perl or C.

Comment: +1 for the extremely interesting use of `declare` (and the link!)